# Bootstrap modal in React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to create a bootstrap modal in React according to the instructions [from here](http://www.qimingweng.com/react-modal-dialog/).

I created a new class with the following content;

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isShowingModal: false
  }
  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({isShowingModal: true});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a onClick={this.openModal}>
        Button Text
        {this.state.isShowingModal ?
          <ModalComponentHere/>
        : null}
      </a>
    )
  }
}
```

However, when I try building the project I get the following error:

```
 Parse Error: Line 6: Unexpected token = while parsing file
```

The error shows up on the line:

```
state = {
```

Why does this error appear?

I don't have much experience with JavaScript but this to me looks like correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you paste your code into the [Babel online REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/), you'll notice that it won't transpile until you check the "Experimental" box.

```
state = {
  isShowingModal: false
}
```

This syntax within a class body isn't (currently) valid JavaScript syntax, it's an experimental proposal for syntax to be included in a future version of the language.

Babel supports [transpiling experimental features to run in today's JavaScript](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/).

This one is es7.classProperties, which is a Stage 0 proposal, so in order to use it you must tell Babel you either want to use Stage 0 features or this one in particular (it defaults to Stage 2).

The above link covers one way to do this, but another common way is to [create a `.babelrc` file](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) which configures the stage of experimental features you want to use, e.g.

```
{
  "stage": 0
}
```

---

Check out React's [ES6 Classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes) documentation for examples of how to create React components by extending `React.Component`, but without the experimental syntax.

This should be equivalent to what your code was intended to do:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isShowingModal: false
    }
    this.openModal = () => {
      this.setState({isShowingModal: true})
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <a onClick={this.openModal}>
        Button Text
        {this.state.isShowingModal ?
          <ModalComponentHere/>
        : null}
      </a>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Isn't there a simpler way of changing the code? I don't want to use additional files.

Comment: Added a new section to show you what you could do instead